# $\varphi:C \rightarrow V$ is a closed immersion iff $\varphi$ is injective and $\varphi^*:O_{V,\varphi(P)} \rightarrow O_{C,P}$ is surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, localization

I’m taking an introductory course on algebraic geometry. I’d like to show that $\varphi:C \rightarrow V$ (where $C$ is a smooth projective curve and $V$ an algebraic variety) is a closed immersion iff $\varphi$ is injective and $\varphi^*:O_{V,\varphi(P)} \rightarrow O_{C,P}$ is surjective.

Here $O_{C,P}$ denotes the local ring of the curve $C$ at the point $P$, which I know is equal to the localization of the ring of regular functions on $C$, $O(C)$, at the maximal ideal corresponding to $P$: $O_{C,P}=O(C)_{m_P}$.

Here’s the definition of an immersion I’m using:

Let $(X,O_X)$ and $(Z,O_Z)$ be ringed spaces. Then a morphism $\varphi: (Z,O_Z) \rightarrow (X,O_X)$ is an **immersion** if it induces an isomorphism of ringed spaces $(Z,O_Z) \cong  (\varphi(Z),O_{X |\varphi(Z)})$.

This means that $\varphi$ induces an homeomorphism of $Z$ on $\varphi(Z)$ and that $\varphi^*$ induces an isomorphism between sheafs of functions $O_{X|\varphi(Z)} \cong O_Z$. Here $O_{X |\varphi(Z)}$ is the sheaf of functions that are locally restrictions of functions in $O_X$. To be more precise, if $Y \subset X$ is a subset of the topological space $X$,

$$O_{X|Y}(V) := \{ f:V \rightarrow k ~|~ \forall y \in V,~ \exists U \text{ open subset and } \exists g\in O_X(U) \text{ such that } y\in U \text{ and } f_{|V\cap U}=g_{|V\cap U} \}$$

Also, we say the immersion is **closed** if $\varphi(Z)$ is a closed subspace in $X$.

Apart from that, I just think I know so far that $\varphi$ being an immersion implies that it is injective and $\varphi^*:O_{V} \rightarrow O_{C}$ is surjective, but I don’t know how to conclude that the induced map on the local rings must be surjective too (should the universal property of localization be used here?). For the other direction, I don’t know how to proceed.

Any help would be welcome as I’m not yet familiar with all these concepts.

Comment: I am not sure your definition of $\mathcal{O}_{X|{\phi(Z)}}$ makes a lot of sense, because this restriction seems to only depend on the topological space. This would mean that given a topological subspace of $X$, there is at most one structure sheaf on it making the 'natural' inclusion an immersion (which is obviously not true).

Comment: I don't know if I am misunderstanding something, but I don't exactly see why $(\phi(Z),\mathcal{O}_{X|\phi(Z)})$ should be a scheme. It might make it easier to answer if you precisely define this new structure sheaf, or go for the 'standard' definition as given in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IO

Comment: @CoherentSheaf I’m using the definitions that were given during the course. We haven’t defined schemes yet, so I can’t really understand your last comment/the standard definition you mentioned yet. I’ve edited the question to provide more details on the definition I’m using (I didn’t know it wasn’t a standard one).